# Datasnap Server on "not installed delphi" PC

Tags: android, sqlite, delphi, client, datasnap

i'm a little confused here.

i got a Laptop and Android to try the project and i want to make client-server software with that.

so, i just learn to do it i need to use datasnap method, and i successfully do it with my own Laptop (delphi installed) as server with sqlite as database, and my android as client.

and then i try copy my database in same directory as when my Laptop as server. and copy my compiled server program (.exe) to other pc without delphi installed, and try again with my android as client, and it fail...

i know it fail when i try to set "clientdataset" provider name properties, and nothing showsup, as when my laptop as server there will be "datasetprovider1" on provider name.

i don't get it -.- i though i did the same like when my Laptop as server. is the server PC must have delphi installed? or i forgot something to install on server PC?

as for note:
i already set the ip destination client to the new ip PC server, i turned off firewall on the new server pc.

any help will be fine, thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy the midas.dll to the other PC. This is needed by the clientdataset.

Comment: Or add `MidasLib` to  project's USES clause.

Comment: i still got the same error, and if i manually enter on "provider name" properties and click active into true, i will get this error
http://s29.postimg.org/ox6fm78s7/Screenshot_34.png